# If $(f(x))^2=1$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $f(x)$ is real-valued continuous, then is necessarily $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=-1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The question is as in the title. Let $f(x): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $[f(x)]^2=1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Then, is it true that $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=-1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$?

Continuity together with real-valuedness seems to imply my guess, but I cannot prove rigorously.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: $f[[0, 1]]\subseteq \{-1, 1\}$ but $[0, 1]$ is connected

Comment: This question is like asking someone find $x$ if $x^2=4.$ Despite knowing the answer everyone would think twice before answering $x=\pm 2$ Haha

Comment: Your should read about Intermediate Value Property of continuous functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not a complete hint, but a guide to a proof**

It's clear that for any given $x$, we have $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) = -1$.

Case 1: Suppose that $f(0) = 1$. Either $f$ is $1$ everywhere on the interval, in which case we're done, or for some $0 < c \le 1$ we have $f(c) = -1$. (Why?)

What can you say about $f$ on the interval $[0, c]$?

What is case 2?

Comment: Interesting.....

Comment: Oh...I was dumb......thank you so much...